# Oracle SQL: Where 2 columns are not null

Tags: sql, oracle

Should be simple enough I think but I'm not getting it and I'm not sure how to explain it without an example to look it up.

```
Table:
 1. A     B 
 2. null  1 
 3. null  null
 4. 1     null
 5. 1     1
```

I want my query to omit anything where both column A and B are null (in example, row 3 would be omitted).

```
select * from Table where (A is not null) and (B is not null)
```

Is just giving me columns where both are present.

Any help would be great.

*edit: changed "return" to "omit"

Comment: Hint:  `OR`, not `AND`.

Comment: bloody hell i knew it was easy... Thanks @GordonLinoff

Comment: Or `where NOT (a is null and b is null)`

Comment: Do you want the query to **return** anything where BOTH COLUMN A AND COLUMN B are NULL? Or do you want it to **exclude** those rows? It seems you want to "exclude" those rows. You wrote "return" those rows - which is exactly the *opposite* of what you need.

Comment: Has you done? You can try like my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter like this:

```
select * from Table where nvl(A,B) is not null
```

Comment: Funny, but why make things complicate and Oracle specific?

Comment: @ miracle173 in SQL maybe ISNULL(A,B) is not null :)

Comment: @LordWilmore: this is an answer to the question!

Comment: @HongVanVit It is not only hard to understand for humans , it is hard to understand for an optimizer, too.

Comment: @HongVanVit If it resolves the issue then please remove the 'Try', and replace it with some actual explanation around your answer, identifying why you believe that this resolves the issue.

Comment: @LordWilmore . Thanks, I will careful.